# Compare the chances of throwing 4 with one dice, 8 with two dice and 12 with three dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Compare the chances of throwing 4 with one dice, 8 with two dice and 12 with three dice.**
**My try:**
$\begin{aligned}\\
\text{The chance of throwing 4 with one dice is} &=\frac 16\\
\end{aligned}\\$
There are 6 ways to get 8 if we throw two dice i.e. $(2,6)$, $(6,2)$, $(3,5)$, $(5,3)$, $(4,4)$, $(4,4)$.
So, the chance of throwing 8 with two dice is = $\frac{6}{36} = \frac 16$
There are 36 ways to get 12 if we throw three dice i.e. $(1,5,6)\times 3!$
$(2,5,5)\times 3!$
$(2,4,6)\times 3!$
$(3,5,4)\times 3!$
$(3,3,6)\times 3!$
$(4,4,4)\times 3!$
So, the total probability to get 12 by throwing three dice is =$\left(\frac 16\times \frac 16\times \frac 16\right)\times 3!\times 6$ =$\frac 16$
Thus comparing the chances = $1:1:1$
$\begin{aligned}\\
\text{But, in my book the answer is} = 36&:30:25\\
\end{aligned}\\$
Though I am not sure if i am correct or not, but please anyone confirm it.

Comment: In your three dice cases, you should not be multiplying by $3!$ when two or three of the dice are the same value.  There are not that many orders.  Similarly, you counted $(4,4)$ twice in the two dice case.

Comment: @RossMillikan would it be $\frac{4}{36}$ for two dice and $\frac{6}{216}$ for three dice case?

Comment: No, for two dice it is $\frac 5{36}$.  You count $(4,4)$ once but not twice.  For each three die combination you need to count the number of orders you can put the numbers in and count that many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chance of throwing an $8$ with $2$ dice is $\frac{5}{36}$ since there are a total of $36$ possibilities and we can have $(2,6) , (6,2), (3,5), (5,3)$ and $(4,4),$ since you don't count the event $(4,4)$ twice.

Consider the following table:

[image]

For $3$ dice there are $6^{3}=216$ total possibilities.
Next we can consider the cases:

- $(1,5,6)$ : these numbers can be arranged in $3!=6$ ways (which are $(1,5,6),(1,6,5),(5,1,6),(5,6,1),(6,5,1)$ and $(6,1,5)$).
- $(2,5,5)$ : these can be arranged in $\frac{3!}{2!}= 3$ ways (i.e $(2,5,5),(5,2,5)$ and $(5,5,2))$
- $(2,4,6)$ :  $3!=6$ ways
- $(3,5,4)$ :  $3!=6$ ways
- $(3,3,6)$ :  $3$ ways
- $(4,4,4)$ : $1$ way.

Total number of ways: $6+3+6+6+3+1=25$ ways.

So comparing we have $\frac{1}{6}:\frac{5}{36}:\frac{25}{216}$ or $36:30:25$ as required.

Comment: Nice explanation! Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome!